# Microservice Ribbon Load balancer Not working

Tags: load-balancing, ribbon, microservices

I try to create one service which consume multiple the same instance of another microservice service.

client microservice pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.demotest</groupId>
    <artifactId>demotest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>happpredictservice</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-feign</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-ribbon</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Dalston.RC1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>
```

//bootstrap.properties file:

```
spring.application.name=predict_service
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888     //this is my configuration //service path not related to my question here

registration_service.ribbon.eureka.enabled=false
registration_service.ribbon.listOfServers= localhost:8083,localhost:8084
registration_service.ribbon.ServerListRefreshInterval=15000
eureka.client.serviceUrl.defaultZone=http://localhost:8761/eureka/
```

//application main class:

```
package com.demotest;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.EnableFeignClients;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
public class HapppredictserviceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HapppredictserviceApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

//clinte service controller class:

```
package com.demotest.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.loadbalancer.LoadBalanced;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonClient;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;

import com.demotest.fiegns.Patient;
import com.demotest.fiegns.RegistrationServiceClient;
//registration_service is application to be called
@SpringBootApplication
@RestController
@RibbonClient(name="registration_service",configuration=Registration_Service_Ribbon_Config.class) //added for ribbon client
public class PredictController {
    // it is feign client instantiation
    @Autowired
    RegistrationServiceClient regClient;

    @LoadBalanced
    @Bean
    RestTemplate restTemplate(){
        return new RestTemplate();
    }

    @Autowired
    RestTemplate restTemplate;
    @RequestMapping("/hi")
    public String gussHi(){
        final String serviceURL="http://registration_service";
        String existingAge=restTemplate.getForObject(serviceURL+"/hi", String.class);
        System.out.println("exisiting age:"+existingAge);
        return existingAge;
    }



}
```

//ribbon configuration:

```
package com.demotest.controllers;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;

import com.netflix.client.config.IClientConfig;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.AvailabilityFilteringRule;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.IPing;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.IRule;
import com.netflix.loadbalancer.PingUrl;

public class Registration_Service_Ribbon_Config {
    @Autowired
    IClientConfig iClientConfig;

    @Bean
    public IPing ribbonPing(IClientConfig config){
        return new PingUrl();
    }

    @Bean
    public IRule ribbonRule(IClientConfig config){
        return new AvailabilityFilteringRule();
    }

}
```

//now I have other microservice to be consumed by the above client. its pom:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.demotest</groupId>
    <artifactId>demotest</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>happregservice</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.2.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-eureka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-gemfire</artifactId>
        </dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>Dalston.RC1</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestones</id>
            <name>Spring Milestones</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/milestone</url>
            <snapshots>
                <enabled>false</enabled>
            </snapshots>
        </repository>
    </repositories>


</project>
```

//the bootstrap.properties file of microservice to be consumed:

```
spring.application.name=registration_service
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:8888
server.port=8083
```

//main class of the microservice to be consumed:

```
package com.demotest;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.cloud.context.config.annotation.RefreshScope;
import org.springframework.cloud.netflix.feign.EnableFeignClients;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScans;
import org.springframework.data.gemfire.repository.config.EnableGemfireRepositories;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@SpringBootApplication
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableGemfireRepositories//this is for gemfire it works perfect not releted to //my question here
public class HappregserviceApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(HappregserviceApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

//the controller class of the microservice to be consumed:

```
package com.demotest.controllers;


import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.UUID;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.cloud.client.discovery.EnableDiscoveryClient;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestBody;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

import com.demotest.entities.Patient;
import com.demotest.repositories.PatientRepo;
import com.netflix.discovery.DiscoveryClient;

@RestController
public class registrationcontroller {

    @RequestMapping("/hi")
    private String getHi(){
        return "hi from original";
    }


}
```

/*I copy and paste the same microservice(the second one) to be consumed and only I changed the port to 8084. for some reason I Iam getting error due to unable to access the service to be consumed by its name. When I try to access the service using localhost: it works. as soon as I chaged to the service name in the RsetTemplate call I am getting the following error:

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Request URI does not contain a valid hostname: http://registration_service/hi */

Answer (score 1):

do not use "_" in "spring.application.name".you can change to "registration-service"